# Necessary and sufficient conditions for two subspaces to be orthogonal

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

This is an exercise in my functional analysis textbook:

> Let $M_{1}, M_{2}$ be subspaces of an inner product space $X$. Show $M_{1} \perp M_{2}$ if and only if $\|m_{1} + m_{2}\|^{2} = \|m_{1}\|^{2} + \|m_{2}\|^{2}$ for all $m_{i} \in M_{i}$.

$M_{1}\perp M_{2}$ means $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in M_{1}$ and $y \in M_{2}$, although this is not explicitly stated in the textbook. The necessity is easy to prove. But how can I prove the sufficiency? I am a little confused because it seems a very basic result but my first attempt led me to
similar computations to those shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794814/is-the-converse-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-false-for-complex-inner-products), so I think I'm missing something. Any help or hint is welcome.

Comment: $||a+b||^2 = ||a||^2 + ||b||^2$ iff $a \perp b$

Comment: $\|a+b\|^2 =\|a\|^2+2\Re(\langle a,b\rangle) +\|b\|^2$. You will need that you can apply this also to $ia$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks. I can see it now.